# how to run electron binary in command line terminal (vty)

Tags: node.js, centos, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have created an electron application with express.js, the reason for developing an express application with the electron is to package an executable which runs without node installed.

I successfully package the application in centos 7. if I double click the application binary going from centos GUI, it runs fine. when I try to run it using the command line terminal login via putty, using `./app` nothing happens, I cannot understand why.

is there any way to run centos binary which generates from electron packager login from putty?

source code as follows, the command I used to package is `npm run build`

Note: when I try to run it using GUI terminal using `./app` it again work fine

main.js

```
 const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
  const path = require('path')
  const url = require('url')

var express = require('express');
var _app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(_app);
let PORT = 3001;
_app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

_app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


  let win

  function createWindow () {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

    win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }))

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.on('closed', () => {
      win = null
    })
  }

  app.on('ready', createWindow)

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit()
    }
  })

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . app --platform linux --arch x64 --out dist/",
    "rpm64": "electron-installer-redhat --src dist/app-linux-x64/ --dest dist/installers/ --arch x86_64",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "myapp",
    "category": "your.app.category.type",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/root/projects/myapp"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "squirrel",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^20.11.1",
    "electron-installer-redhat": "^0.5.0",
    "electron-packager": "*",
    "electron-prebuilt": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-terminal-open": "^0.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

since this is a web server like application I was able to deploy it with node packages to where node.js os does not install and run it without any issues. below are the steps

in my node app on centos 7, I installed all the dependancies using `npm i`
then I downloaded the node.js linux binaries to the app folder and tar.gz it.

then I move it to a different centos pc which does not have node installed.

I untar the tar.gz file and set the PATH to node.js folder where in my app folder in following way `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/my/app/node/bin`

then I run `npm start` and it works fine without any issues. I didn't use electron here and couldn't find the answer to my question with the electron.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible by just defining the display parameter.**
Run below command before you electron process.

> $ export DISPLAY=:0

> ./run you appplication process

this is working for me.